# Is there absolutely no way to have html forms not refresh the page after submit WITHOUT jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, socket.io

So I am now working on learning node.js servers with socket.io, and having the form submitted would recreate a new web socket connection. I have read that it could be fixed using jQuery to alter the submit action of the form in order to not have it refresh the page, but right now I just want to see if it could be done without jQuery or AJAX.
my html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Socket</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="" action="">
        <input name="message" id="message" type="text" placeholder="message" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="send" type="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

where main.js :

```
const socket = io.connect('83.130.85.31:7776');

const button = document.getElementById("send");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const form = document.getElementById("form");

const sendMessage = (event) => {
    socket.emit("message", {message: message.value});
    message.value = "";
};

form.addEventListener("submit", sendMessage)

socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log(data.message);
})
```

I know my code is very naive, I just focus on understanding implementation of socket.io right now and it was a small test.

Comment: Make the button `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`, and/or prevent the default action in the handler.

Comment: There's no form, what is being submitted?

Comment: jQuery is just a JS library, it can't do anything that native JS can't do.

Comment: the second argument to `addEventListener()` should just be the name of the function, not a function call.

Comment: Oops, I indluded the version without a form, My bad.

Comment: @IdanCohen You know you can fix that, don't you?

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I fix my code with your advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `Event.preventDefault()`

```
const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("message", {message: message.value});
    message.value = "";
};

button.addEventListener("click", sendMessage);
```

You can do the same thing with the form's `submit` handler:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", sendMessage);
```

Comment: If I use that code I can't submit using ENTER, no?
It would only work for clicking on the button

Comment: @IdanCohen Yes, but your current one suffers from the same problem. That's a separate issue, solved by not using the click event.

Comment: @IdanCohen Correct. The solution would be to use a `submit` listener on the form instead of a `click` listener on the button.

Comment: Yes, I included the wrong version of my code.
I am sorry.
so I should add a listener to my <form> on main.js and insert the functionality there?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you,  preventDefault() works!